# final vs volatile guaranntee w.rt to safe publication of objects

Tags: java, java-memory-model

From the book Java concurrency in practice :

> To publish an object safely, both the
>   reference to the object and the
>   object's state must be made visible to
>   other threads at the same time. A
>   properly constructed object can be
>   safely published by:
>
> - Initializing an object reference from    a static initializer
> - Storing a reference to it into a     volatile field or AtomicReference
> - Storing a reference to it into a  final field of a properly constructed 
>     object
> - Storing a reference to it into a     field that is properly guarded by a
>     lock.

My questions are :

1. What are the the differences between bullet points 2 and 3 ? I am interested in the difference between `volatile` approach and `final` approach in terms of safe publication of the object .
2. What does he mean by final field *of a properly constructed object* in point 3 ? Before starting the bulleted points authors already mentioned that they are talking about a properly constructed object (which I assume is not letting the `this` reference to escape ). But once again why did they mention about properly constructed objects ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> What are the the differences between bullet points 2 and 3 ?

- `volatile` basically means that any writes to that field will be visible from other threads. So when you declare a field as volatile: `private volatile SomeType field;`, you are guaranteed that if the constructor writes to that field: `field = new SomeType();`, this assignment will be visible by other threads that subsequently try to read `field`.
- `final` has quite similar semantics: you have the guarantee that if you have a final field: `private final SomeType field;` the write to that field (either in the declaration or in the constructor): `field = new SomeType();` won't be reodered and will be visible by other threads *if the object is properly published* (i.e. no escape of `this` for example).

Obviously, the main different is that if the field is final, you can only assign it once.

> What does he mean by final field of a properly constructed object in point 3 ?

If, for example, you let `this` escape from the constructor, the guarantee provided by the final semantics is gone: an observing thread might see the field with its default value (null for an Object). If the object is properly constructed this can't happen.

---

Contrived example:

```
class SomeClass{
    private final SomeType field;

    SomeClass() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                SomeType copy = field; //copy could be null
                copy.doSomething(); //could throw NullPointerException
            }
        }).start();
        field = new SomeType();
    }
}
```

Comment: If after construction I change the state of the object refered to by field like `field.setX(new X())`, is that change also guaranteeed to be seen by other threads when we declare it as volatile ? Or does it only give the initialization safety ? What about final in this case ?

Comment: No, only `field` gives you visibility guarantee on (re-)assignement. Unless `x` is also volatile, `field.x = new X();` (or your setter example) provides no such guarantee.

Comment: Same goes for final, with the corollary that if all the members of `field` are final too and are immutable, `field` is immutable and is therefore thread safe.

Comment: @assylias I read your answer a few times but still couldn't get it. Since field is final, there won't be any reordering, why would new thread won't see "field" attribute of "this"? Are you saying, it's because constructor isn't completed yet?

Comment: You even have more guarantees when using `final` fields: "[The other thread] will also see versions of any object or array referenced by those final fields that are at least as up-to-date as the final fields are." ([source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5))

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference in what the effects of publishing `volatile` vs `final`, except that `final` can only be set once in the constructor, and thus what you read should never change.

I believe a *properly constructed object* is indeed what you refer to, an object whose `this` reference did not escape its constructor and has been published in a safe manner to the thread that it is used in.